# Getting screen dimensions in a shell script

Tags: screen, shell

To run a game on my Nexus 5 (5.1), I need to change my screen resolution. I'm trying to write a shell script that will detect the current resolution and change it, basically a toggle.

I know that I can actually change the resolution using `wm size XXXXxYYYY`, but I don't know how I can check the current resolution. I know very, very little about regex, and I tried to figure out how to pull the results from `dumpsys display`, but I really had no idea what to do.

How can I get the current screen resolution for a shell script that will use `if` to check it, like a toggle?

Answer (score 1):

you nearly answered your question already. `wm size` shows you the current resolution.

Saving the output of the screen reoslution into a shell variable: `A=$(wm size | busybox cut -c16-)`